# Feed in variable to jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

Hi i want to use the following function

```
$('#add-regular').click(function(){
        $.gritter.add({
            // (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification
            title: 'This is a regular notice!',
            // (string | mandatory) the text inside the notification
            text: 'This will fade out after a certain amount of time. Vivamus eget tincidunt velit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et <a href="#" style="color:#ccc">magnis dis parturient</a> montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.',
            // (string | optional) the image to display on the left
            image: 'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/59268975/jquery_avatar_bigger.png',
            // (bool | optional) if you want it to fade out on its own or just sit there
            sticky: false,
            // (int | optional) the time you want it to be alive for before fading out
            time: ''
        });

        return false;

    });`
```

The image variable is dynamic, how do i change it, i am using asp.net, also i want the javascript function to be called when a button is clicked, please let me know how i can do this. Thanks

Comment: that values ​​can have the image? There are several buttons for each variation, or where it is dynamic?

Comment: I will like to change the value in this line "image: 'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/59268975/jquery_avatar_bigger.png',"  in my code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

ASP:

```
<input id="imageValue" value="<%=value%>" type="hidden" />
```

JS

```
$('#add-regular').click(function(){
        $.gritter.add({
            // (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification
            title: 'This is a regular notice!',
            // (string | mandatory) the text inside the notification
            text: 'This will fade out after a certain amount of time. Vivamus eget tincidunt velit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et <a href="#" style="color:#ccc">magnis dis parturient</a> montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.',
            // (string | optional) the image to display on the left
            image: $("#imageValue").val(),
            // (bool | optional) if you want it to fade out on its own or just sit there
            sticky: false,
            // (int | optional) the time you want it to be alive for before fading out
            time: ''
        });

        return false;

    });
```

Comment: How will i load it automatically,at the moment it has the "$('#add-regular').click(function(){", how do i load it up automatically from code behind, thanks